# Avoiding Redundant Functions in Navigation Sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I'm very new to web development stuff so I'm having trouble googling the correct terms here.

The sidebar navigation is working, but the scripts are ugly and redundant.

Is there a way to clean this up? Like store the link id and html file location in an array and just have one script that does the lookup?

I don't need "code for me", just a nudge in the right direction.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <link href="./styles/main_style_sheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#navigation_link_1').click(function(){
        $('#content_area').load('location_1.html');
      });       
    });
  </script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#navigation_link_2').click(function(){
        $('#content_area').load('location_2.html');
      });       
    });
  </script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#navigation_link_3').click(function(){
        $('#content_area').load('location_3.html');
      });       
    });
  </script>  
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#navigation_link_4').click(function(){
        $('#content_area').load('location_4.html');
      });       
    });
  </script>  


  <body>

  <div class="container">
    <div id="concept-sidebar"">
      <h4 style="text-indent: 0px;"> <strong> My Sidebar </strong></h4>
      <div class="container" style="width:100%">
        <div class="list-group">
          <a id="navigation_link_1" 
             class="list-group-item custom" 
             > First Item </a>
          <a id="navigation_link_2"
             class="list-group-item custom"> Slowly Changing Dimensions (SCD) </a>
          <a id="navigation_link_3"
             class="list-group-item custom"> Important System Fields
          </a>    
          <a id="navigation_link_4"
             class="list-group-item custom"> Reference Data
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may copy all scripts to some file filename.js and give the path of that in your HTML file like <script src="filename.js"></script> . In src, if in the same folder then no issue otherwise give path to the file.

Comment: While doing web development, its good to keep javascript, and css in different folders and we just provide path in html file.

Comment: @Error_2646 did you have the time to check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this (and since you asked for a direction and not a solution I'll give give you a general instruction for one of the solutions:):

1. Instead of settings the click-event-handler on each element - select all the relevant elements and have a click event on all of them:
   `$('.list-group-item').click(function(){ ... })`
   The selection here is on all items that have the class `list-group-item`, which in your case is the `<a>` elements you are looking for.
2. Extract the relevant id from the `<a>` you have (for you can use regex for that, for example). Another option - use the `data-*` attribute and get the number from that attribute (`<a data-id="1">` and `$(el).data('id')`).
3. Load the content based on the `id` you just got:
   `$('#content_area').load('location_' + id + '.html');`